# How to generate Icon Font type of icons with iconmoon.io?

Tags: css, sass, icons, frontend

I need to generate and download icons from icon-moon.

Problem is cus needs to be in font-icon format. I don't know how to recognize that format from the prefix like svg.

Here is what I get as generate options from icon-moon:

[image]

Which of these formats is font icon format?

UPDATED:

This files I get when download this selected icons:
[image]

Comment: That's the options overlay, try downloading and the font files should be included

Comment: I updated my post with screeenshot of donwloaded files

Comment: I think there are not that files.

Comment: I think you need to go to the "Generate font" tab and download from there instead of the "Generate SVG" tab you are showing in your screenshot.